# Redirecting from getInitalProps in React/Next.js

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I am using React and Next.js and trying to redirect a user from a page when the data for that page is not available using `Router.push('/another-page')`.

To do this I am checking for a status code in `getInitalProps` and applying a conditional. It looks like this:

```
  const statusCode = action.currentArticle ? 200 : 404

  if (isServer) res.statusCode = statusCode

  if (statusCode === 404) {
    Router.push('/')
  }
```

The status code is being set properly and it makes it inside the conditional, at which point I am greeted with this error: `No router instance found. You should only use "next/router" inside the client side of your app.`

Actually, I am getting the same error no matter WHERE in the component's lifecycle events I try to redirect, and am getting little info online about this error.

The pattern of redirecting from `getInitalProps` can be seen in this next.js wiki: [HERE](https://github.com/zeit/next.js/wiki/Redirecting-in-%60getInitialProps%60)

Any ideas on why this error is occurring or how to fix it are much appreciated ;)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

With Next.js (and any universal react rendering) your code is executing in two different environments. First in Node (on the server) and then in a browser. Next does some work to provide unified functions that run in both these environments but they're very different. Next can't and doesn't keep this from you. It seems like you just loaded a page in your browser but here's a little more detail on what's really going on…

**On the client/browser:**

- Type url in the address bar (localhost:3000 or whatever), press enter.
- GET request goes out to the server (Node).

**On the server/Node:**

- GET request comes in.
- Node gives you a request and a response object.

  - Maybe you have some Express routing/middleware.
- At some point Next's `render()` function is called with the request and response objects.
- Next runs `getInitialProps` and passes in the request/response.
- React `renderToString()` is called which calls the following React lifecycle methods:

  - `constructor()`
  - `componentWillMount()`
  - `render()`
- React creates a string of HTML that gets sent to the client.

^ This is Node. You can't access `window`, you don't have `fetch`, and you can't use the Next Router. Those are browser things.

**Back on the client:**

- HTML is downloaded and rendering begins.
- Links to js/css files in the HTML are downloaded/run.

  - This includes js code compiled by Next.
- React `render()` is run which associates the downloaded HTML (the DOM) with a React virtual DOM. The following React lifecycle methods will run:

  - `constructor()`
  - `componentWillMount()`
  - `render()`
  - `componentDidMount()`
- All other lifecycle methods (updates) will run when props/state change.

^ This is the browser. You have `window`, you have `fetch`, you can use the Next Router. Now you don't have the Node request/response but that seems to catch people up less.

Ref: [Component lifecycle](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#the-component-lifecycle)

Comment: I didn't realize the `render` was happening on the server - that's where I went wrong. This is a super informative answer! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 4):

The way works like @Shi said, but there is not `server` in getInitialProps. Instead of that, there should check `window`:

```
getInitialProps({res}){
 if(typeof window === 'undefined')
  res.redirect('/');
 else
  Router.push('/');
}
```

Comment: I didn't have access to the response object, my code needed to run client side. I used this suggestion above, omitting the getInitialProps to only check for the window object, and replacing the res.redirect('/') with a <Link /> component, and it works.

Answer (score 3):

You can redirect from `getInitialProps()` like this:

```
import Router from 'next/router'

static getInitialProps = (ctx) => {
    // On server
    if(typeof window === 'undefined'){
      res.writeHead(302, {location: '/dashboard'})
      res.end()
    } else {
    // On client
      Router.push('/dashboard')
    }
    return {}
}
```

See https://github.com/zeit/next.js/issues/649

Comment: i get this error next time i visit the url: Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client

Comment: Are you using a custom server? Are you sending any headers with `getInitialProps` from `_app`?

Answer (score 2):

next/router is not available on the server that's way you get an error saying that router not found, next/router can only be used on the client side.

For you to redirect a user inside getInitialProps in the server you can use:

```
getInitialProps({server,res}){
 if(server)
  res.redirect('/');
 else
  Router.push('/');
}
```

Comment: `TypeError: res.redirect is not a function`

Answer (score 1):

To make sure the page never render, we need to add `await new Promise(() => {})` to end. The promise no needed resolve anything.

```js
Home.getInitialProps = async ({res}) => {
    if(res) {
      res.writeHead(302, {location: '/dashboard'});
      res.end();
    } else {
      // window.location.href = '/dashboard';
      // Or with SPA redirect
      Router.push('/dashboard');
    }
 
    await new Promise(() => {});

    return {}
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't it cause memory leak?

Answer (score 0):

I found this https://www.npmjs.com/package/nextjs-redirect to be very simple and solved the issue for both client and server side.

pages/donate.js

```
import redirect from 'nextjs-redirect'
export default redirect('https://paypal.me')
```